# Hyperion-Android: ServiceLoader can’t load custom Plugin

Tags: android, kotlin

I faced an issue in [Hyperion github](https://github.com/willowtreeapps/Hyperion-Android). I want to add my custom item into **Hyperion** menu.
As I figure out if I remove something from core-libs they would be removed successfully and vice versa. *But if I add custom `Plugin` - nothing happens.*

I've tried different versions of **Hyperion** it also does not affect the result.
Also, here what I've checked additionally:

1. Proguard
2. Imports
3. Dependencies
4. LayoutInspector
5. Sources with debugging
6. Packages
7. Flavors
8. Extract into a separate module
9. `@AutoService` annotation
10. set `minifyEnabled false`

**Plugin:**

```
import com.google.auto.service.AutoService
import com.willowtreeapps.hyperion.plugin.v1.Plugin
import com.willowtreeapps.hyperion.plugin.v1.PluginModule

@AutoService(Plugin::class)
class TestPlugin : Plugin() {
    override fun createPluginModule(): PluginModule? {
        return TestPluginModule()
    }
}
```

**Module:**

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.willowtreeapps.hyperion.plugin.v1.PluginModule


class TestPluginModule : PluginModule() {
    override fun createPluginView(layoutInflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup): View? {
        return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.htest_plugin_item, parent, false)
    }
}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
def hyperionVersion = '0.9.27'
    debugImplementation "com.willowtreeapps.hyperion:hyperion-core:$hyperionVersion"
    debugImplementation "com.willowtreeapps.hyperion:hyperion-attr:$hyperionVersion"
    debugImplementation "com.willowtreeapps.hyperion:hyperion-crash:$hyperionVersion"
    debugImplementation "com.willowtreeapps.hyperion:hyperion-measurement:$hyperionVersion"
    debugImplementation "com.willowtreeapps.hyperion:hyperion-recorder:$hyperionVersion"
    debugImplementation "com.willowtreeapps.hyperion:hyperion-shared-preferences:$hyperionVersion"
    debugImplementation "com.willowtreeapps.hyperion:hyperion-timber:$hyperionVersion"
```

[image]
[image]

> NOTE: on screenshots v0.9.26. But I've tested also v0.9.27, v0.9.25, v0.9.24.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks like the problem is related to the processing of `@AutoService` annotation. Make sure that you have added an annotation processor to the project.

You should add the following annotation processor to the `build.gradle` file.

for **Kotlin** project:

```
kapt 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc6'
```

for **Java** project:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc6'
```

Comment: Awesome  I've thought that should be implemented with the lib as I found it in pom config. Thanks 